# Which is the fastest structure for processing integers(add,read from thousands of nodes)

Tags: java

I am trying to find out which structure would be the fastest, because i have a problem with my code. I have a large amount of data to store. Maybe thousands of nodes are needed. My first thought was to create an ArrayList and then i started adding integers to use them  later. This ArrayList will be useful for fast accessing bytes in Random Access Files. So, i put the first node, which represents a pointer to the first entry in a Random Access File. Then, i put the second, at the same way, and so on..

My program takes too long when putting the integers in the ArrayList. 
Could i fix my code using a faster structure??

Answer (score 2):

Yes,

you can use [LinkedList](http://www.firatatagun.com/linkedlist/2011/10/23/), your arraylist have amartized O(1) insertion but when you have a huge arraylist and it needs to be resized, it will take long time to allocate a new arraylist, copy the current elements and continue.

eg: if you have 10 million elements in your arraylist and it s full, when you insert one more, your arraylist has to double the size of current and then copy all the elements to the new one. this is very expensive operation.

If you use [LinkedList](http://www.firatatagun.com/linkedlist-notes/2011/07/07/) you have O(1) insertion but not random access. So if you want to access to nth element, you will have to traverse all the nodes up to n. it takes O(n). but do you really do that.

So linkedlist is you option. possibly, [doubly linked list](http://www.firatatagun.com/circular-doubly-linked-list-via-c/2011/05/21/).

If you want fast reads as well as fast insertion, you can use Dictionary, HashMap. You have O(1) writes and reads, if and only if you have a perfect hashing.

But again, internally, HashTable, Dictionary uses arrays so once your dictionary grows too large, you will have the same problem, moreover, each time your array expands, your hashcodes are re-calculated.

You can use Trees with logn writes and reads.

You can use Skiplist with logn writes and reads.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed despription. I know thata Hash strucrures are very fast, but at this time i just need to keep a sequence of pointers to a random access file. So,i need to keep the numeber of the byte where an entry occurs. So, my structure will contain a large sequence of integers. I did not know about doubly linked list. Thank you for mentioning. Do you know if LinkedList requires fragmented memory?? In order to avoid having the problem of reallocation.

Answer (score 1):

An `ArrayList` is clearly not the fastest thing here, because the `ArrayList` does not contain `int` but the `Integer` wrapper types. Therefore a plain array `int[] intArray` have the lowest overhead.

On the other hand: if you can omit the list/array completely and do the calculations instantly, this would save some more overhead. This leads in the direction to not do microoptimization but to think about the problem and perhaps use a completely different algorithm.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunateley, i have to keep somewhere the information i mentioned above, because i have to write them in files on disk, later.